# Prime operator for sinusoidal testing function in self-term approximation for Thin Wire using Method of Moments (MoM) $s_m^{'}(x_p)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, antennas, radio-frequency

I am implementing thin wire method of moments using W.Gibson's "Method of Moments in Electromagnetics". The approximation for self-term using piecewise sinusoidal basis function is given as

[image]

where, sm(x) is the sinusoidal testing function.

In the same book for EFIE, prime operators are used to differentiate terms for source and testing triangles. However as this equation is written for self term, I am not sure what the term sm'(x) means here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term sm'(xp) denotes the divergence of the testing function.

Comment: Is it actually the divergence or the derivative?

Comment: To make this answer helpful to future readers, who may be dealing with similar but not identical issues, please consider adding a couple of explanatory sentences about how you reached this conclusion.

Comment: @KyleKanos in 1D cases it is the derivative